# How to get Address Field to display correctly with Autocomplete?

Tags: ajax, entities

I want to create a postal field for addresses in the Philippines.

I have set up a sandbox site with a content type that has just one field, of type addressfield and using the autocomplete widget. Only one country is allowed.
However, when I create content, all I can see is the field for entering the address and the Google map, I cannot see the Address Field fields.
When I enter an address in the Philippines, it gets coded correctly by Google and displays properly on the map. However, if I then try to save the field, it tells me that obligatory fields ("Address 1" and "City" in this case) are missing.

If I click on "enter one manually", then nothing happens.

This is only accessible by a logged-in user, so I presume that caching is not the problem.

I have tried using FF45 and the lastest release of Chromium, all to no avail

I also presume that I must have made a mistake setting something up, but i cannot work out what that might be...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there is an incompatibility between Addressfield Autocomplete and/or the geocomplete.js library it uses, and the version of JQuery that gets bundled with Drupal 7.

The solution is to install the [JQuery Update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update), and set the JQuery version to 1.10